# Fill NaN values based on key

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to fill null values in one dataframe based on another dataframe based on a key found in both dataframes.

```
df

parcel     ID
1234       NaN
4586       lmnop
5960       wywy
```

```
df1        

parcel     ID
1234       abcd
4586       lmnop
```

Since the parcel number is the same in df and df1, I want to fill only the null values in the ID column based on df1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `combine_first()` is good approach, but you need to set index first - in this case the column `parcel` is common in both:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'parcel': [1234, 4586, 5960, 9999],
    'ID': [np.nan, 'lmnop', 'wywy', np.nan]
    })

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'parcel': [1234, 4586, 9999, 8888],
    'ID': ['abcd', 'lmnop', 'xxx', 'nonexistent']
    })

df_out = df.set_index('parcel').combine_first( df1.set_index('parcel') )
df_out = df_out[df_out.index.isin(df.parcel)].reset_index()
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
   parcel     ID
0    1234   abcd
1    4586  lmnop
2    5960   wywy
3    9999    xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `map` which allows you to use a dictionary to map values.

```
na_dict = dict(zip(df1.Parcel,df1.ID))

df.ID.fillna(df.ID.map(na_dict))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not fill in the NaN values. Does it matter if there are other NaN values within the dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas-dataframe-combine-first):

```
df.combine_first(df1)
```

Output:

```
   parcel     ID
0    1234   abcd
1    4586  lmnop
2    5960   wywy
```